# How to find typing status of EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-view

I want to find typing status of EditText when the user starts typing or stop typing. I have found `addTextChangedListener` but it continuously firing event. Any help would be much appreciated. You can refer typing status from any chat application.
P.S: Please give me suggestion other than `addTextChangedListener`

Comment: What is wrong with the listener? What do you mean by typing status?

Comment: Typing status means user currently typing or not into EditText @MuratK.

Comment: Just give some more information what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this by creating custom `EditText`

```
public class CustomTypingEditText extends CustomEditTextNormal implements TextWatcher {
    private static final int TypingInterval = 800;

    //your listener interface that you implement anonymously from the Activity
    public interface OnTypingModified {
        void onIsTypingModified(EditText view, boolean isTyping);
    }

    private OnTypingModified typingChangedListener;

    //members you would need for the small thread that declares that you have stopped typing
    private boolean currentTypingState = false;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable stoppedTypingNotifier = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //part A of the magic...
            if (null != typingChangedListener) {
                typingChangedListener.onIsTypingModified(CustomTypingEditText.this, false);
                currentTypingState = false;
            }
        }
    };

    public CustomTypingEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.addTextChangedListener(this);

    }


    public CustomTypingEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.addTextChangedListener(this);

    }

    public CustomTypingEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    public void setOnTypingModified(OnTypingModified typingChangedListener) {
        this.typingChangedListener = typingChangedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //part B of the magic...
        if (null != typingChangedListener) {
            if (!currentTypingState) {
                typingChangedListener.onIsTypingModified(this, true);
                currentTypingState = true;
            }

            handler.removeCallbacks(stoppedTypingNotifier);
            handler.postDelayed(stoppedTypingNotifier, TypingInterval);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int after) {
    }

}
```

And here is listener,

```
etMessage.setOnTypingModified(new CustomTypingEditText.OnTypingModified() {

    @Override
    public void onIsTypingModified(EditText view, boolean isTyping) {

        if(isTyping){
             Log.i(TAG, "onIsTypingModified: User started typing.");
        }else{
             Log.i(TAG, "onIsTypingModified: User stopped typing");
        }
     }

});
```

Comment: What is CustomEditTextNormal  ?

Comment: That is my custom EditText class which has custom fonts. You can use EditText

Answer (score 2):

Define addTextChangeListener for you editText like this,this is perfect for getting writing callback.

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString()) && s.toString().trim().length() == 1) {
                    updateIsTyping("y");
                    isType = true;
                } else if (s.toString().trim().length() == 0 && false) {
                    updateIsTyping("n");
                    isType = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I was use this for my chat app and this is working fine till now.

Comment: I am not getting false result

Comment: Debug your code and check again false code execute or not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to fire an event when the user starts typing, and when the user stops typing. The addTextChangeListener is part of the solution, but you should combine it with a timer and a boolean.

Each time the user starts typing, set the boolean to true and record the time. Check the time regularily - if a couple of second or so has passed since last time the user has typed, consider it as if the user has stopped typing, set the boolean to false and reset the timer.